# I need help in identifying this bush

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image]I have a delightful bush in my garden which is self seeded. It has white blossom in spring, delicate, light green hazel-type leaves (but more delicate) and clusters of black, shiny berries in the autumn which the birds don't seem to like. The nearest look alike is a mock orange, but it isn't

[image]

Comment: Welcome April! It's nice to meet you! I saw that you put additional information into an answer by mistake, so I added it in here for you. (Don't worry, I made that same mistake on my first day here!) To edit your posts, just press the gray word "edit" that's at the bottom. Your question will open back up and you can add or subtract anything you want! Our system can be confusing, so I recommend checking out the pages of our [help]. If there's ever anything you need help with, just leave a comment here and someone will come along and help you!

Answer (score 4):

Erm, no I don't think its a Philadelphus, the leaves are too heavily impressed and serrate for it to be that. I wonder if its Rhodotypos scandens - berry formation is quite distinctive because they're held in clusters of four; they are black when fully ripe. Presumably you've seen the berries, so check this link for images and information https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodotypos

Comment: Interesting species. A member of Rosaceae, but with only 4 petals.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Can't claim credit for the ID, I just came across it on Google, although its name was familiar to me once I did. Must have been a bird dropped seed for it to appear on its own

Comment: It was not a critique, only a noteworthy commentary. Rhodotypos seems to have only 4 petals, which is very seldom in Rosaceae.

Comment: I side with Bamboo's ID.  The picture she gave is almost identical to April's and the berries are the definitive answer, Hairy Mock Orange is orange to red not black and not in clusters of four.  https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrTcdcbCu1YW6YAPF4nnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Hairy+Mock+Orange+Berries&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - I did not take it as a critique of any sort, not sure why you thought I might or had, but rest assured, I certainly didn't

Comment: Thanks Bamboo and Giacomo Catenazzi. Here's a picture of the berries

Comment: Sorry...I'm new to this site and am having trouble adding another photo. I'll keep trying!  But yes, the berries are black and in clusters of four. It is good to finally find the correct name. It is a delightful bush.

Comment: @April, you should add any pictures to your question, not in a comment (think of comments as temporary). There's an "edit" button under your question.