# What's this shrub with white flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs

A friend took the images below in a Vienna park in late April.  The woody shrub has flowers with four petals; the size I'm not sure of, but I'd guess they're at least a couple inches across and probably more.  There are some old fruits in the pictures which we believe are from the same plant.  I don't pick up on too many distinctive features, but perhaps a knowledgeable person here will be able to recognize the plant. (The images have more resolution than the StackExchange question format shows, so you may want to follow the link to the source.)
[image][image]

Comment: See this Q & A here, I believe its the same shrub https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/32546/i-need-help-in-identifying-this-bush/32548#32548

Comment: @GardenerJ yea, thats the question I already linked to above

Comment: @Bamboo & all, thanks for quick pointer; it does seem Rhodotypos is correct.  Despite the flower, I was pretty sure because of the leaves it wasn't a Philadelphus (which Bamboo id'd for me last year, thanks!).  A bit strange it's a close relative of Kerria given its habit, although the leaves are similar to Kerria's leaves.

Comment: This is Viburnum mariesii.  A bit 'naturalized' but one of the coolest shrubs us humans use in our landscapes.

Comment: https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A86.JyTniwdZAFIAnm0nnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Viburnum+Mariesii&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002

Comment: @stormy, This can't be doublefile Viburnum - it's not beautiful enough!  Seriously, V. plicatum f. t. Mariesii has an inflorescence with the petals on sterile outer flowers, whereas this plant has 4 petals coming from a single calyx. Also, the berries on this plant are tightly clustered, while the Viburnum berries are looser.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes plants find themselves in less than optimum conditiions; ie) too shady, planted in the midst of other plants that do better in shade.  Hey, waiting for others to take a stab at this!  Rhodotypos?

Comment: Sigh, yup, Rhodotypos looks like the best ID.  Way to go, Bamboo!!  Grins!!